# Why use openid connect ID token if the access token had all the claims and can be revoked?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using oauth2 authorization code flow with the ASP.NET core 2.2 AddJwtBearer. My token end point returns JWT access toke with all the claims needed for checking the user's permissions. 
I can send this token as the bearer for any Web API call and the standard .net code can use those claims to check permissions eg `[Authorize(Policy="somePolicy")]`.
One of the claims points at an internal session key that we can revoke.

So my question is why would I need an ID token or even a refresh token?
The claims and other details are in the access token so what would an ID token add to this?
Having to use a further call to a userinfo end points send to be a waste if the info is in the Auth token?
If I can revoke the session that Auth token points at, surely I don't need a refresh token and can have longer life Auth tokens?

I've read lots of examples and comparisons but most computations between just oauth2 and enhanced with openid connect seem to be with very basic oauth2 not using JWT etc and so written to exaggerate the differences. 
So I'm unclear when both are using the same authorization code flow and JWT tokens, what the team advantages are in using the id token in my situation??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your context, it seems that OpenId Connect is not necessary for your situation. It really adds value when you are implementing single sign-on (SSO). In that case the Identity token can also be used on SSO logout.

Having additional claims about the identity in the access token is also a waste. Having to send all this information on each call. Especially when you need the information only once (a Spa may persist the information in memory). It's better to have some api (endpoint) expose the information when requested.

About the access token, you can't revoke it. You may be able to revoke authorization, but the access token remains valid until it expires. You want invalid access tokens to short-circuit as soon as possible in the pipeline, before policies are evaluated.

Please note that it's not a common scenario where the api can revoke access by using an internal session key. Most api's are 'session-less' and fully rely on the access token. Because that's the purpose of a JWT, being self-contained, not having to contact the authority to verify the token.

Perhaps you can use a long-lived access token because in your situation the authorization is determined at another level. But are you capable of detecting when the token is compromised? And where are you going to check it? In every api and client? Or would you rather let the authority take care of it (single responsibility)?

When implementing security you should look at the design, the responsibilities, where to do what. Let the authority, that issues the tokens, take care of authentication and client/resource authorization. The Api, being the resource where the business rules (policies) are implemented, can take care of (user) authorization.

The problem with a long-lived token is that when it falls into the wrong hands, it allows access until it expires or, in your case, until you detect something is wrong. Where a short-lived token always allows access for a short time, making it almost not worthwhile for a hacker to obtain a token for the time it can be used.

With short-lived access tokens you'll have to use refresh tokens. The authority can verify on each call whether a new access token should be issued. Of course here counts the same, this only applies to the situation where you are actually verifying the request. Tokens in itself are not safe. You'll have to add some level of security, e.g. check the ip address. But having the authority to take care of it and using one-time-use refresh tokens already does add security.

In my experience with oidc/oauth2, the access token is mainly used to grant client applications access to a resource (on behalf of a user). Where scope claims define the accessible functionality and the sub claim identifies the user.

Authorization can be implemented on different levels and doesn't have to be part of the access token. In fact, permissions should not be part of the access token at all.

So your setup may be fine. But I wouldn't use long-lived access tokens for the reasons already mentioned. Plus they are not managable. You can't update the access token when someting changes in the flow, e.g. when a scope is added.

Comment: Thanks that's really detailed. OK so If I'm sending an access token in the header of each Web API call, surely that would need all the claims(permissions) that were given when I logged in so they can be used by `[Authorize(Policy="somePolicy")]`?

Comment: @user1677973 It's not a good idea to put [permissions in the access token](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/). But yes, you can add claims to the token that can be used for policies. But you can also use other sources. An alternative is to use an external authorization server, e.g. [policy server](https://policyserver.io/). The open-source version is a local implementation. But you can also implement [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased) and use IAuthorizationService and policies.